Does System F Support Cut Elimination?
I've been studying type systems and proof theory, and System F (the second-order lambda calculus). Does System F support cut elimination?. I know strong normalization can be proved for system F, but I was wondering if cut elimination has also been proved for it.

Isn't the usual set of typing rules already without a cut rule? Are you instead asking if adding such a cut rule would not alter the typing relation (i.e., the cut rule is admissible)? How does that differs from the substitution lemma $\Gamma \vdash t:\tau \ \ &\ \  \Gamma,x:\tau \vdash u:\sigma \implies \Gamma \vdash u[t/x]:\sigma$ ?

It'd help if you could point to a reference that defines system F as you understand it.
